# how to display a calendar controller from a fxml file in javafx

Tags: javafx, gridpane

Is that possible to display a calendar controller from scene builder? I am trying to display a calendar which ideally has to be linked to a data property and time slot. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using scene builder, but you can manually edit your fxml to add a DatePicker.  I created a simple example that shows a date picker and when the date is chosen it displays it in a Text field below.

The fxml looks like:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="datepicker.DatePickerController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" />
    </padding>

    <DatePicker fx:id="datepicker" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#handleDatePickerAction"></DatePicker>

    <Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</GridPane>
```

And the controller looks like:

```
public class DatePickerController
{
    @FXML
    private Text actiontarget;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datepicker;

    @FXML
    protected void handleDatePickerAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
    actiontarget.setText(datepicker.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```